# Are cracks in a wall around a cantilevered bathroom signs of impending collapse?

Tags: old-house

My home was built in 1910 and the bathroom above the foyer has a corner that isn't supported by a wall underneath it. That corner of the bathroom is where the bathtub is. When going up the stairs you can see several cracks on the wall that make me very nervous to even be in the bathtub. Should I add support or do I just leave it and trust the structural engineering that's lasted this long? If I need to add support, what kind and how? Any sort of help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

The wall continues up into the full sized attic as the attic stairwell wall, but ends at the attic floor. [image: foyer view of ceiling]

[image: house falling apart]

Comment: This is something you do need someone(structural engineer, building contractor) in to look into how the floor is supported.  If supports are needed, then the floor below must be checked also, to see if it can be used as is, or more supports added below.

Comment: Is it possible there is a steel/wood beam under it and that's why there's no supporting wall?

Comment: There's definitely no steel beam under it. Possible that the wood floor beams used to support that corner sufficiently. When the tub was added, they cut into the floor boards for the basin to sit lower.

Comment: We can't possibly answer that from here. Either open up the wall to see what's what or get an expert on site.

Comment: Rather than being cantilevered (requiring long and strong floor joists or beams) could it be hanging from structure above? The latter could safely support the corner with properly fastened sturdy studs or with a steel cable or rod. Does the corner deflect when you fill the tub to a standard level? Before pulling off drywall check deflection by holding up a 2x4 vertically that almost reaches up to the corner on a maked spot below.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I never thought of checking that. I'll be sure to do that and then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

You should neither panic over cracks in walls, nor ignore this odd situation.  I think if I owned this I would poke some holes in the ceiling beneath the "bathroom extension" to look at the framing there, and maybe bring in an expert to look at it.

I've seen cantilevered open staircases, and I've seen cantilevered rooms (though they are usually over garages) and corridors.   But here, to cantilever BOTH the stairs and the bathroom, without creating any real openness seems unlikely.  Maybe not original design?   Maybe there was not a bathtub there or even a bathroom.   Maybe this was done incrementally and stretched beyond the original framing design.  Worse case whoever installed the bathtub also notched or weakened the already-sketchy framing for the drain.  Best case, the framing in there is twice as solid as anything we build today.  It's worth looking.

My not-so-informed guess is that is in fact an addition to the upper floor because it is out of character for a house of that era with a beautiful staircase like that.  Someone, at some point, decided they wanted more space upstairs and damn the grand staircase.   Did that same person include the bathtub and its plumbing in the design and engineer the framing for it?  I would want to know.

Comment: The way the layout is set up is the original floor plan, but not sure that the room was a bathroom originally. The "closet" in the bathroom is where your find the door to go up the stairs to the full sized attic. Not ideal but we deal with it. My husband redid all the plumbing in the bathroom and when he had the wall removed from the back of the shower/tub we could see that they cut into the floor when they installed the tub. It didn't seem to have any more framing added than any other portion of the floors.

Comment: Did your husband take any pictures of the open walls/floors?

Comment: No, but the drywall piece isn't fully installed or mudded yet, so I could take it off and do a more thorough inspection of that area.

Comment: Do.   Try to look under the tub.  Buy a borescope if it would help.  Get someone experienced in framing to look at it now before you tile it over.   It's relatively easy to poke through the ceiling beneath and then repair it, but you have an opportunity now to look in the open wall that will be a lot harder once you tile it.  And you might have access from there underneath the bathtub so you don't have to damage the ceiling beneath.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from what you've given us, your house isn't falling apart (at least no more quickly than usual). Plaster is strictly cosmetic, not structural. It may or may not be advance warning of other issues.

Diagonal cracks are usually caused by uneven settling. If you haven't already had an expert check for that, that's where I'd start. They can opine on the overhanging room while they're there.

A house ideally starts out straight, square, and plumb. It never remains so. Unless that change is unusually rapid, it may not be worth fighting.

Comment: It's the horizontal cracks that go directly around the corner of the "floating" floor portion that worry me most. The picture was mostly to show the unsupported corner and you can't really see those cracks well. I know that most of the cracks I've mudded are superficial but these ones reappear within weeks of being fixed, every time.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you get someone to inspect it and see if there is an actual issue? Those old houses were built before building codes so quality varies greatly.
It's possible it's only superficial cracking but it could also be a serious issue.

Comment: I would love to be able to have someone inspect it, but I cannot afford anything at this time. The house is definitely failing in a lot of ways for being up to building codes.

Comment: If you can't afford to have it inspected (a few hundred dollars), how are you going to afford to do anything else about it?

Comment: By using stuff I already have on hand if needed. That's why I had posted in this thread to get input from others on if addressing it is absolutely necessary at this time.